# How to build a ggplot geom_point() for my data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that I transposed and now looks almost exactly (there are more columns) like this:

```
           amiloride  BRD-K14844937 flupentixol 
PC3        35.28         63.64       54.02   
VCAP        0.00        -65.70      -53.37   
A375       -2.69          0.00      -96.26   
A549        0.00          0.00        0.00   
HA1E        0.00        -95.85       55.20  
HCC515     18.63        -48.56        0.00  

> str(ttoPlotDF)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  56 variables:
 $ amiloride                  : chr  " 35.28" "  0.00" " -2.69" "  0.00" ...
 $ BRD-K14844937              : chr  " 63.64" "-65.70" "  0.00" "  0.00" ...
 $ flupentixol                : chr  " 54.02" "-53.37" "-96.26" "  0.00" ...

> names(ttoPlotDF)
 [1] "amiloride"                   "BRD-K14844937"              
 [3] "flupentixol"
```

I would like to plot the data using a ggplot() + geom_point() so that each column of nine numerics appears as a vertical scatter at the same x position. Then I would move to the next column of nine numerics and plot those at the same position, i.e., stacking my results before moving onto the next.

I suspect this involves dataframe manipulation to get the `aes()` correct. However, for the time being, my knowledge is limited. I would appreciate any help.

Also, and this might be a bit of an ask. How would I:

1. make each PC3 point, VCAP point, A375 point etc., to be the same symbol across the plotting column stripes?
2. Make all points that fall within [-100:-90] to be a different colour from the points not within that small range?

**DATA**

```
structure(list(amiloride = c(" 35.28", " 0.00", " -2.69", " 0.00", 
" 0.00"), `BRD-K14844937` = c(" 63.64", "-65.70", " 0.00", 
" 0.00", "-95.85"), flupentixol = c(" 54.02", "-53.37", "-96.26", 
" 0.00", " 55.20")), .Names = c("amiloride", "BRD-K14844937", 
"flupentixol"), row.names = c("PC3", "VCAP", "A375", "A549", 
"HA1E"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your description, I think you are looking for something like this. As you described, I think you want to have your data in long format. I added row names into the data, converted it to a long-format data, and added a new column indicating whether numbers are staying between -90 and -100. Onece the data is ready, I drew the following graphic. I assigned symbols for each level of `Group`. Colors are assigned based on the column, `check` in `out`.

```
library(tidyverse)

out <- rownames_to_column(mydf) %>%
       gather(key = variable, value = value, -rowname) %>%
       mutate(check = between(value, -100, -90))

ggplot(data = out, aes(x = variable, y = value, color = check, shape = rowname)) +
geom_point() +
labs(x = "Group", shape = "Group") +
guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(amiloride = c(35.28, 0, -2.69, 0, 0, 18.63), BRD.K14844937 = c(63.64, 
-65.7, 0, 0, -95.85, -48.56), flupentixol = c(54.02, -53.37, 
-96.26, 0, 55.2, 0)), .Names = c("amiloride", "BRD.K14844937", 
"flupentixol"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("PC3", "VCAP", 
"A375", "A549", "HA1E", "HCC515"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Almost! I'm afraid I probably failed in my description. Rather than separate plots, I would like them all on the one e.g., values for
A375, A549, HA1 etc., for amiloride are grouped on the same X position and then BRD-K14844937 are grouped on the next X position. 

I have 40 drugs (e.g., amiloride) with their nine cell line responses (e.g., A375), so I would like to get them all on the one graph.  

This is the best images I could find:
https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/plots/ggplotintro/group1.png
Notice how the dots are stacked.

Comment: @AnthonyNash I think I know what you mean. Let me work on revision.

Comment: @AnthonyNash I updated the code. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @AnthonyNash I think I got it in a wrong way. Let me clarify your point. Seeing what you said, I think you want to have `amiloride`, `BRD.K14844937` and `flupentixol ` on x-axis. Is that right?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. I am getting an `evaluation error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double]` when I try to use rownames_to_column. I know what it means but I'm not sure how to solve it with immediate effect.

Comment: @AnthonyNash Can you type dput(head(ttoPlotDF)) in your R Console and share it? Then, I may be able to see what is happening on your side.

Comment: I've done a terrible job editing, but it's in my original post. I had to trim it down as the output was pretty long. Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyNash Something is not right in your updated code. Can you try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163778/discussion-between-jazzurro-and-anthony-nash).

Comment: Can do, just on the train. Will be in touch soon. Thanks.